# Why there are many page fault during full GC

Tags: windows, memory-management, garbage-collection, operating-system, jvm

It is Window 2003 server.

We are running some performance test, and what we see is:

1. In first 5 hours, the page fault/sec is very small, like 10 or 20
2. In the last 1 hour, the page fault jumps to 500 page fault/sec
3. In the last 1 hour, we see a lot of full GC.

Note that we have enough RAM like 64G, and the whole system is only using half of them, so there should not be many hard page fault.

What I want to know is that when JVM is doing GC, is it expected to see a big amount of soft page fault/sec compared to no GC?

Answer (score 1):

[Incremental garbage collectors](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/master/manual/html/glossary/i.html#term-incremental-garbage-collection) interleave their execution with the [mutator](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/master/manual/html/glossary/m.html#term-mutator). This can cause two kinds of problem:

1. The mutator may change an object that the garbage collector has already analyzed (for example, updating a reference). In this case the collector needs to be informed about the change so that it can take account of the change.
2. In the case of a [copying collector](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/master/manual/html/glossary/c.html#term-copying-garbage-collection), the mutator may want to look at an object that the collector has moved. In this case the collector needs to be informed about the attempt to read from the moved object so that the mutator can be redirected to the new copy of the object. (Using the [forwarding pointer](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/master/manual/html/glossary/f.html#term-forwarding-pointer) stored in the "[broken heart](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/master/manual/html/glossary/b.html#term-broken-heart)".)

Problem (1) can be solved by the collector placing a [hardware write barrier](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/master/manual/html/glossary/w.html#term-write-barrier) on the pages that it has finished analyzing. Problem (2) can be solved by the collector placing a [hardware read barrier](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/master/manual/html/glossary/r.html#term-read-barrier) on pages containing objects that have been moved.

When the mutator hits these barriers, [page faults](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/master/manual/html/glossary/p.html#term-page-fault) are generated, and the fault handler runs the appropriate function from the garbage collector.

(I don't know for sure if this is how the JVM garbage collector works on Windows, but an increase of page faults is to be expected during incremental garbage collection.)

Comment: I don't think most garbage collectors on most platforms actually use tricks like this, though I've heard of a few more exotic ones doing it (e.g. one by Azul). Still, very good explanation! +1

Comment: You might be surprised: for example, the [Boehm collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector) uses write barriers (it's a non-moving collector so it doesn't need read barriers) and it's used in GCJ and Mono, among other projects.

Comment: Read and write barriers, yes, but we're talking about *hardware* r/w barriers. I was under the impression that in implementations that have full control over the generated code (i.e. not Boehm but GCJ, Mono, .NET, JVMs, LuaJIT, etc. as well as interpreters with sophisticated GCs) it's a software thing rather than a hardware thing: A couple of instructions added to every piece of code that touches a reference.